# Tensorflow object detection api get predictions sorted by bounding box coordinates

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, captcha, object-detection-api

I trained a neural network to solve simple captcha using tensorflow object-detection API, but when I output the predictions with the following code:

```
for index, value in enumerate(classes[0]):
object_dict = {}
if scores[0, index] > threshold:
    object_dict[(category_index.get(value)).get('name').encode('utf8')] = scores[0, index]
    objects.append(object_dict)
```

I get predictions in random order with every function run. I asked a question earlier, and I was advised to try using the coordinates, but I could not find a way to connect the classes and the coordinates of the box that is associated with this class. Example of solved captcha is attached, so  I need a way to output predictions in order from left to right.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlxxl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `boxes[0]` is an array of shape num_boxes * 4, where the first value in the box is xmin, this can get you the indicies of the boxes, sorted by the one with the lowest xmin (the one that starts further left).

```
indices = np.argsort(boxes[0][:,0])
```

Then you can use these indices to sort the boxes, scores, and classed, as follows:

```
sorted_scores = scores[0][indices]
sorted_boxes = boxes[0][indices]
sorted_classes = classes[0] indicies
```

If you wanted to, for example, sort by xmax instead, you'd use `np.argsort(boxes[0][:,2])`.
You can play around with using 0-3 to sort by xmin, ymin, xmax, and ymax.

Comment: Excessive self promotion may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help] and specially the last section of [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): Avoid overt self-promotion. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).